# How to get around RestSharp "A strongly-named assembly is required"

Tags: c#, rest, plugins, microsoft-dynamics, restsharp

I am using RestSharp for a Dynamics plugin, this requires the project to be a DLL. I get this error message when running the plugin:

> An unexpected error occurred from ISV code. (ErrorType = ClientError) Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): pluginname.PluginEntryPoint: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044) If you contact support, please provide the technical details

My code is using .NET Framework 4.6.2 and the RestSharp version is 106.6.10

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
var body = " {\"data\": [{ \"name\": " + name + ", \"parent_id\": \"0\", \"short_code\": " + shortcode + ", \"billable\": \"yes\",  \"assigned_to_all\": \"yes\", \"billable_rate\": \"37.50\"}]}";
var client = new RestClient("https://rest.tsheets.com/api/v1/jobcodes");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");//authorisation token
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
return true;
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Please provide the code that you try to run

Comment: I've updated the post to include code, it is for TSheets integration

Comment: If there are other projects in solution, be sure that all projects use the same version of RestSharp dll or package.

Comment: the other projects dont use RestSharp at all

Answer (score 0):

In your app.config or web.config, find the row for RestSharp. Something like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Resrsharp.." publicKeyToken="35bf3856bd364e31" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Check the version numbers at this row and actual DLL version.